# How to use $lte function in mongodb aggregation operations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongoDB, i entered a collection which holds data of employee in the company including their salary.I calculated average salary of employee using $avg operation in aggregation.Now if i want to calculate avg salary of only those employee who has salary less than certain value, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't have access to a mongodb to test the query but in your case you would just add a `$match` query object in your aggregation 'pipeline' just before your `$avg` grouping.

Something along the lines of:

```
[{'$match':{'salary':{'$lt':199}}}, {'$group':{...}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "salary": {
                $lte: 100
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$groupKey",
            "avg": {
                $avg: "$salary"
            }
        }
    }
])
```